# Certification ORACLE Java

Tags: java, oracle, certificate

Насколько я мог нагуглить, ORACLE ушел из России. Ранее слышал, что их сертификаты по Java неплохо бустят тебя при устройсте на работу, но скептически к этому относился. Сейчас для портфолио хочу получить OCA. Ибо он котируется в других странах, а не только в РФ. Реально ли получить данный сертификат в РФ (например удаленно)? Или нужно в др. страну ехать и искать филиал?

Сейчас работаю программистом модемов, EHS5 от Cinterion (Java ME)

Читал об этом в интернете. Нашел несколько контор которые предлагают, якобы, аналогичную сертификацию. Но оно актуально только для РФ. Хотелось бы международный сертификат

Comment: Насколько я знаю, сертификат - это уже давно не бумажка, просто запись на сайте оракла о том, что тебе выдан сертификат.  Сдают его удалённо.  Поэтому если и возникнут сложности, то только с оплатой.

Comment: "...Сдают его удалённо..." - очень здорово, что не нужно филиал искать др. стране. Спасибо за ответ. Буду искать теперь где удаленно сдать.

Answer (score 0):

На сайт oracle если зайти через vpn, то он начинает нормально работать. И всю информацию по экзаменам и курсы там можно найти. Ссылка:
https://education.oracle.com/buy-exam

[image: Скрин сайта Oracle]